# Pagination always missing 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a pagination code that fetch data from DB and show them in Table paginated,   but always missing the last row added in the database, I have no idea why..

this my code ;

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                    $page=$_GET['page'];
                    }else $page=1;

            $obj=new action_a_DB();
            $totall= $obj->getNmbLgForPages() ; // number of all articles.
            $pagination=new pagination($totall,10 /*number of content per page*/,$page,5 /*number of button to show*/);
            $start = $pagination->Start ; 
            $end = $pagination->End ;
            // get the info from the db 
            $total_page =   ceil($totall/10);
            $result = $obj->getAllArticle($start,$end) ;
                                }
```

pagination.php

```
...
public function Show_Pagination($link,$get='page',$div_class_name='pagination')
    { 
    if($this->Pages==1)return; 

    echo'<div class="'.$div_class_name.'">'; 
    if($this->Page_number>1)echo '<a  href="'.$link.'&'.$get.'='.($this->Page_number -1 ).'">Pre</a> ';

    else echo '<a >Pre</a> ';

    //print button

    $this->Buttons=(int)$this->Buttons;

    $start_counter  =   $this->Page_number-floor($this->Buttons/2);          

    $end_conter     =   $this->Page_number+floor($this->Buttons/2);  

    if($start_counter<1) $end_conter=$end_conter+abs($start_counter);       

    if($end_conter>$this->Pages) $start_counter=$start_counter-($end_conter-$this->Pages);

    if(($this->Page_number-floor($this->Buttons/2))<1)$end_conter ++; 

    for ($i=$start_counter;$i<=$end_conter;$i++)
            {

            if($i>$this->Pages || $i<1)continue;        //no print less than 1 value or grater than totall page

            if($i==$this->Page_number)echo ' <a  class="cur">'.$i.'</a> ';       

            else echo ' <a  href="'.$link.'&'.$get.'='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';       
            } 
    if($this->Page_number<$this->Pages)echo '<a  href="'.$link.'&'.$get.'='. ($this->Page_number +1 ) .'">Suiv</a> ';

    else echo '<a >Suiv</a> ';       

    echo'</div>';

    }
...
```

my funtions in action_a_DB.php

```
function getAllArticle($Start, $End){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles order by id desc limit $Start , $End";
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Req Invalide: ' . mysql_error());
        //return mysql_fetch_array($req);
        return $req;
  }

  function getNmbLgForPages(){
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT count(id) from articles") or die('Erreur :'.mysql_error()); //
    $totall=mysql_result($query,0);
    return $totall;
  }
```

My table

```
                    </tr>
                    <?php if(mysql_fetch_row($result)!=0){ 
                    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="first style1"><?php echo $data['titre']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $data['descrition']; ?></td>
                        <td><img src="img/edit-icon.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/hr.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/save-icon.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="save" /></td>

                    </tr></tbody> <?php } 

                                        ?>

            <tfoot><tr id="nav"><td colspan="5"><div> <?php
            $pagination->Show_Pagination("index.php?param1=value1",'page','pagination');

             ?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="total"><td colspan="5"><?php    echo 'Page : '.$page.'   sur     '.$total_page.'  Nombre totales d\'articles: '.$totall.'' ; ?></td>
            </tr>
                <?php } else{ ?>
            <tr><td align="center" colspan="5">Rien a afficher</td>
            </tr></tfoot>
                <?php } ?>

                </table>
```

How can i Fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: This is way too much code. Please try narrowing it down and remove code that has nothing to do with the question (eg table layout, functions that don't fetch data, ..)

Comment: subject line suggests to me that the math on the limit may be wrong

Comment: @kingkero all that code needed to explain  the probleme, I think it'll help you to help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was here

```
 <?php if(mysql_fetch_row($result)!=0){
```

I have to use **mysql_num_rows** not **mysql_fetch_row**

So I use

```
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
```

Why, When my query is executed, it returns  a result set with a pointer to the first record. Then each fetch returns  a line and moves the pointer to the next line or returns false if there is no next row in the result set, then the while to process all the results. In my  case, the first line of my resource is used in  if so it fails in the display.

Now work fine, thanks to **Bovino** for explain and to you all